# SQLAllocConnect success,but SQLConnect fail

Tags: odbc

I had made connector/ODBC successfully,then I write some code:

```
SQLHENV henv;       
SQLHDBC phdbc;      
SQLRETURN retcode; 
retcode = SQLAllocEnv(&henv); 
retcode = SQLAllocConnect(henv,&phdbc);    
if(retcode == SQL_SUCCESS)
{
    char *a="cc_mysql";
    char *b="chen1991";         
    retcode = SQLConnect(phdbc,(SQLCHAR*)a,SQL_NTS,(SQLCHAR*)b,SQL_NTS,(SQLCHAR*)b,SQL_NTS);
             }
```

but I failed to connect. I debug it and found that the  SQLAllocConnect return true ,but SQLConnect return -1,I can't understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is your call to SQLConnect failed and you need to call SQLError to get the error back. I'd just be guessing but may be the DSN cc_mysql does not exist or your username/password are invalid, or mysql does not allow that user to access it etc.

BTW, you should really be writing at least ODBC 3 applications these days and to do that you should be calling SQLAllocHandle, SQLSetEnvAttr (to set ODBC behavior), SQLDriverConnect and SQLGetDiagRec.